# Get the referred object of a Ruby variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, class, activerecord

I am working on a task where I get a set of classes( ActiveRecord classes to be more precise) and I want to get their names. I do this by iterating over this set and applying methods like `#name` to the elements of the set.
Something like this:

```
array_of_classes.map {|class| class.name}
```

The problem is that some of the elements in this array are not initialized so when I call `#name` on them I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ClassName
```

To find out if a variable or a constant has been initilized I can use the `defined?`keyword like this:

```
> defined? UnInitializedClass
nil
> defined? InitializedClass
"constant"
```

The problem with this is that things get more complicated when we have an array of **both** initialized and uninitialized elements and we iterate over the array to get their elements. The `defined?` keyword will be applied to the iterators themselves and not to the classes( or constants or variables) that these variables point to.

```
> [UnInitializedClass, InitializedClass ].map {|x| defined? x}
["local-variable", "local-variable"]
```

Is there a way to apply the `defined?` keyword on the `constant` the variable `x` holds?

If not, do you have any idea on how I can find out the uninitialized elements of an Ruby array?

Another idea might be to access each element using the square brackets method `[]` but `defined?` is still not applied on the referred constant

```
> defined? array[0]
"method"
> defined? array[1]
"method"
```

Comment: How does defining the array not blow up? If I try `[Asdf]` I immediately get `NameError: uninitialized constant Asdf` before I can even start trying to iterate.

Comment: I don't create it by myself. It's created when I call `#reflect_on_all_associations` on a model.

Comment: eagerly loading classes should solve all of this (model classes will be all loaded)

Comment: The problem is that the class that causes the problem has been removed from the project.

Comment: The problem is that the class that is causing the problem has been removed from the project, yet for some reason the `#reflect_on_all_associations` method is still returning it.

Comment: Interesting. Is the association that points at the old, missing class not gone yet, too?

Comment: Weird that you get this behavior. Were your objects serialized somehow (e.g. Marshal) and the codebase changed in the meantime?

Comment: What do you mean by "the class that causes the problem has been removed from the project"? Do you mean `Object.send(:remove_const, :Klass)` has been executed? In that case an `uninitialized constant` exception will be raised if you reference an array containing `Klass`, What can you do about that? Not a thing, since you can't execute `defined?(k)` for elements `k` of the array without first referencing the element, which raises the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Or a shorter version of pdobb's code:

```
array_of_classes.map {|klass| klass.name rescue nil}.compact
```

Comment: A shorter version of faulty code is not an improvement.

Comment: Cary, the OP mentioned "that worked!" in his comment on pdobb's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you can have an array of constants, some of which aren't defined... but, you could use a rescue block to filter out the valid constants.

```
array_of_classes = 
  array_of_classes.each_with_object([]) { |klass, acc|
    begin
      klass
    rescue NameError
      # Do nothing
    else
      acc << klass
    end
  }
```

After that you should be safe to use the constants as per usual.

Comment: That worked! Maybe it's not the most elegant solution but it works for me.

Comment: May we see an example? I think not, for the reason given in your opening clause. If the array is `[A,B]` and `B` has not been defined, you will immediately get a syntax error (I.e., that isn't rescued). Moreover, what if both `A` and `B ` have been defined, but `A #=> 'cat'`?

Answer (score 1):

The only way this question makes sense is that the array contains not constants and uninitialized constants (the latter would immediately raise a syntax error), but strings containing the names of initialized uninitialized classes. In that case you could do this:

```
class A
end 
B = 'cat'

['A','B','C'].select do |s|
  Object.const_defined?(s) ? Object.const_get(s).is_a?(Class) : false
end
  #=> ["A"]
```

Note that this concerns classes generally, not just particular ones.